# BASH - quickly determine the number of lines in a file that start with a Uppercase

Tags: bash, file, lines, counting

How can I quickly determine the number of lines in a file that start with a Uppercase?

I think with regex this would be [A-Z]*), but I don't want to "read line" ...
something more faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option if you don't want to use a `read` loop would be to use `grep`, with the `-c` switch which counts matching lines, like this:

```
grep -c ^[A-Z] the_file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, great :)) how can I measure the reaction time ?

Comment: Depending on the contents of the file, the character class `[[:upper:]]` is better than `[A-Z]`

Comment: `root@linux:~# time(grep -c ^[A-Z] /root/list)`
`1005578`

`real    0m0.192s`
`user    0m0.178s`
`sys     0m0.011s`

Comment: for languages that aren't english. For example `printf "%s\n" {A..Z} È Á` -- try filtering that with `grep -v '[A-Z]'` and then with `grep -v '[[:upper:]]'`

Comment: `root@linux:~# time(grep -c ^[[:upper:]] /root/list)`
`1005578`

`real    0m0.188s`
`user    0m0.165s`
`sys     0m0.018s`

Comment: @glennjackman , so you say using [[:upper:]] is more accurate

Comment: @eichertc, I'd say it's more complete.